# Why am I getting the error message "No match for argument: mod_evasive"?

Tags: apache, centos

I am running a Centos 8 distribution of Linux with httpd running on it to serve web sites and cannot get mod_evasive to install. I updated, installed httpd-devel then tried to install mod_evasive but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

mod_evasive is not yet available from the default CentOS 8 repos.

You can, however, install the Raven repo and get it from there:

https://centos.pkgs.org/8/raven-x86_64/raven-release-1.0-1.el8.noarch.rpm.html

```
sudo dnf install https://pkgs.dyn.su/el8/base/x86_64/raven-release-1.0-1.el8.noarch.rpm
sudo dnf --enablerepo=raven-extras install mod_evasive
```

Alternatively, you can just install the mod_evasive rpm:

```
sudo dnf install https://pkgs.dyn.su/el8/extras/x86_64/mod_evasive-1.10.1-33.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Thank you It's been a while since I used Centos and I'm not completely familiar with what's available with 8 by default just yet.